# How do I embed icons into text within Squib only on certain cards?

Tags: ruby, squib

**Here's exactly what I want to do: Whenever one of my cards has within the Ability column of my .csv the text "Gains 1 tribute", the output is "Gains 1 [my tribute icon]" within the text box of the card, formatted so that it's part of the regular Ability text. Is this possible?**

P.S. Also, how do I make icons have transparent backgrounds? I've saved them from game-icons.net as such, but they always display with a white background. Here's what I've tried:

```
require 'squib'
require 'game_icons'

Squib::Deck.new(cards: 4, layout: %w(hand.yml layout.yml), width: 825, height: 1425) do
  background color: '#FFFFFF'
  rect x: 0, y: 0, width: 825, height: 1425, x_radius: 38, y_radius: 38
  data = csv file: 'country.csv'
  png file: data['Art'], layout: 'Art'
  png file: 'textbox.png', x: 50, y: 890
  png file: 'titlebox.png', x: 65, y: 30

  tribute = data['Tribute']
    colorl = tribute.collect { |x| fg(x) }
    background color: tribute.map.with_index { |x,i| bg_grad(x, attrr[i]) }
    text str: data['Tribute'], layout: :Tribute, color: colorl
    svg file: tribute.collect {|x| icon(x)}, layout: :TributeIcon
  end

  %w(Title Ability Quote Type Subtype).each do |key|
    text str: data[key], layout: key, markup: true
  end

  %w(Tribute Power Dominion).each do |key|
    svg file: "#{key.downcase}.svg", layout: "#{key}Icon"
    text str: data[key], layout: key
  end

  save_png prefix: 'country_'
end
```

However, I'm now getting an expected-end-of-input error!

Answer (score 2):

Since the `Squib::Deck.new() do...` construct needs either single values or lists for everything, you'll need to use something like `.collect` on an existing array, possibly several, because I don't see how to insert images into text.

So, you'd need something like...

```
ability = csvfile['Ability']
ability_offset = ability.collect { |x| choose_offset(x) }
ability_icon = ability.collect { |x| choose_icon(x) }
ability_icon_x = ability.collect { |x| choose_icon_loc(x) }
```

Then use those lists in your `text` and `svg` commands as you normally would, maybe with an empty stub image when there's none to display, for consistency.

As for the images, looking at a couple of samples, *I* would use the black-on-transparent icons and hand- or automatically-edit the files so that the `<path>` includes a `fill="white"` attribute, and maybe `stroke="black"` as well, if that's useful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Really annoying that I can't format code in my comments to show you what I'm doing! I added your block, but I'm not much of a programmer and I don't think I'm doing it right; it's just giving me a NameError message. Do I need to change the x's you included? As for the images, wouldn't fill="white" give me a white background? I'm hoping to keep the transparent background.

Comment: Collect is definitely helpful. But I'm also surprised to see TWO `text` calls that use `data['Ability']`. Why the two calls? It seems to me that `Ability` should be taken out of the `%w( ).each` construct and the one call above it should reference `layout: 'Ability'`. Also, another way to limit your calls to only a few cards is with the `range` option.

Comment: OK? So could someone please explain exactly what I I actually put into the block to get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: Oh! Sorry, it was stupid of me to assume you weren't coming to Squib from outside of programming. Yes, you need to write the methods I call `choose_offset` and so forth. That's _probably_ too detailed a discussion on basic Ruby for a comment thread, but if you can work from an example, I played with a lot of this a couple of weeks back [on GitHub](https://github.com/jcolag/AttaCard-Generator). It's nothing _exciting_, but plays with a lot of the same ideas and I ended up using the same SVG trick.

Comment: I've tried working from your example, but seem to be getting stuck. I updated the original post with the code since I can't format it here in the comments. Would you mind letting me know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!